# Use analytical functions on a small data set but with all the data in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I have an Oracle large table (~50M rows). 
I need to create a report that will show last/next values for only a part of the big table. 
For example, the table looks as following, with sessions since 2010, but I need to present only the sessions occurred in 2019, but their last values can be from 2018 or earlier. 
If I filter the table to take only the sessions from 2019 then the last sessions will be also since 2019. 
**I don't want to run on the whole table** as it is very large table and the query is complicated. It will take a lot of time. 
The table looks as following:

[image]

And the expected result should like this:
[image]

Any ideas how to generate it so it would run efficiently and fast?

Comment: Is the table partitioned by anything? Any indexes?

Answer (score 2):

Typical query:

```
select session_id, client_id, session_date, last_session, next_session
  from (
    select session_id, client_id, session_date, 
           lag (session_date) over (partition by client_id order by session_date) last_session,
           lead(session_date) over (partition by client_id order by session_date) next_session
      from sessions )
  where session_date >= date '2019-01-01' order by session_id;
```

but it does **table access full**. You can filter only 2019 data and run subquery only for rows which needs it:

```
with t as (
    select session_id, client_id, session_date,
           lag (session_date) over (partition by client_id 
                                    order by session_date) last_session,
           lead(session_date) over (partition by client_id 
                                    order by session_date) next_session
      from sessions 
      where session_date >= date '2019-01-01')
select session_id, client_id, session_date,
       nvl(last_session, (select max(session_date) 
                            from sessions 
                            where client_id = t.client_id 
                              and session_date < t.session_date)) last_session,
       next_session 
  from t order by session_id;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dfcbcf8cbf15a6eadba1926e7d7ee816)</sup>**

I created two indexes:

```
create index idx_sessions_date on sessions(session_date);
create index idx_sessions_client_date on sessions(client_id, session_date);
```

and plan table looks promising, both indexes used:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1923279194
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                     | Rows  | Byte
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                          |     6 |   31
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                |                          |     1 |    2
|   2 |   FIRST ROW                    |                          |     1 |    2
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)  | IDX_SESSIONS_CLIENT_DATE |     1 |    2
|   4 |  SORT ORDER BY                 |                          |     6 |   31
|   5 |   VIEW                         |                          |     6 |   31
|   6 |    WINDOW SORT                 |                          |     6 |   21
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SESSIONS                 |     6 |   21
|*  8 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_SESSIONS_DATE        |     1 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why bother with the `lag()` and `lead()` in the CTE?

Comment: `Lag` combined further with `nvl` determines whether to use subquery for particular row. `Lead` can be in outer query or inner, it is counted only for _2019 rows_, small part of data.

Comment: . . Is there really an advantage to running the subquery on only a subset of the rows?  That is my actual question.

Comment: I don't know @Gordon, I tried both ways and don't see the difference. No advantages, no disadvantages. Query may be simplified to get rid of subquery like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c077eab432365479ca8f8222d5091fe), 
I doubt it will be faster (same execution plan) but it has shorter syntax. Thanks for upvote.